# How to scroll first div overflow then after that body scroll by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, javascriptcore

```html
<body>
    <div class="container" style="overflow-y:scroll, width:100%,height:500px">
        <div class="overFlow" style="width:60%,height:"1000px,background-color:red,display;flex,align-items:center,justify-content:space-between">
        </div>
        <div class="formCContainer" style="width:40%">
            <form>
            <label style="width:100%">
                <input placeholder="enter your name" type="text/>
            </label >
            <label style="width:100%">
                <input placeholder="enter your password" type="password"/>
            </label>
            <button typle="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see in the code above, I have defined three divs under the body tag: the first div has 100% width and height of 500px; the second div is a child of the first div and has 60% width and height of 1000px, causing it to overflow; and the last div has 40%. Now I want that when users scroll, they first finish scrolling div.overFlow, and then after finishing that, they are able to scroll body.

Please do do not recommend jQuery solutions.

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Please run your code through a debugger first.

Answer (score 1):

### **UPDATED ANSWER**

OP needed a sticky sidebar. If someone stuck in this same problem just keep reading.
Checkout the [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-forked-2mr26y) for hands on apporoch.

We could easily use CSS property [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to achieve this result.

```
.element-you-want-to-stick{
    position:sticky;
    top:0; 
}
```

> Here we use `top:0;` to make it stick to the top.you could use `bottom` ,`left`,`right`

---

### **OLD ANSWER**

> So you want to scroll overflow element and then body

The behavior you describe is usually achived by setting CSS [`overscroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior) to `auto`

```css
    .overflow{
       overscroll-behavior:auto;
    }
```

Comment: first try to scroll when the pointer is above the overflow element. we'll start from there.

Comment: .overFlow{
 overflow-y: auto;
  overscroll-behavior: auto;}

Comment: above CSS property is not working as I want it to, do not scroll div. overFlow

Comment: bro, please take look here [link]( https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-j70yz1) @Shankaja

Comment: some website references for help just like that as it happens on this website [link](https://www.nobroker.in/packers-and-movers-in-delhi).

Comment: the [link](https://www.nobroker.in/packers-and-movers-in-delhi) you sent uses position sticky .if that's you want It'll be easy. Please respond immediately. I can recreate that for you.

Comment: please do navigate me also you can send me your codeSandbox link

Comment: I've update the answer with more context. and working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-forked-2mr26y)  if you got any question happy to help